# How can I post JSON data to the body of a request from .net?

Tags: .net, ruby, service

How can I post JSON data to the body of a request from .net?

I am using .net 2010 and apparently thr httpclient is not available to me. I converted data to JSON and now need to post it to a Ruby api and they want it in the body.

Comment: Are you using any specific libraries? RestSharp? It allows you to specify data in the body.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using any specific libraries, you should be able to use `System.Net.WebClient`.
Here's an example:

```
var wc = new WebClient();
wc.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
var result = wc.UploadString("http://your/api/url", "POST", your_json_string);
```

assuming that `your_json_string` is a `string` variable which holds you data in JSON format.